# Spider not found in scrapyd.schedule

Tags: django, scrapy, scrapyd

i'm trying to start scrapyd from django
The scrapyd code is like this

```
unique_id = str(uuid4()) # create a unique ID. 

settings = {
    'unique_id': unique_id, # unique ID for each record for DB
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'
}

task = scrapyd.schedule('scrap_lowongan','josbid', settings=settings)
```

However, i'm getting

```
scrapyd_api.exceptions.ScrapydResponseError: spider 'josbid' not found
```

My folder structure is something like this

```
Bitalisy>
     Bitalisy
     Scraping>
          views.py (Schedule scrapyd from here)
     scrap_lowongan> (scrapy Project)
         scrap_lowongan>
             spider>
                 jobsid.py
             settings.py
             pipelines.py
         scrapyd.conf
         scrapy.cfg
```

Note that i'm using scrapyd.conf because i have two scrapy project. The scrapy.conf

```
 [scrapyd]
 http_port   = 6801
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that you must add :

```
scrapyd = ScrapydAPI('http://localhost:6801')
```

And after restarting scrapyd it's working 
like charm. Read more the documentation [here](https://github.com/djm/python-scrapyd-api/blob/master/docs/source/usage.rst)

Comment: Yeah, i can't accept my own answer until tomorrow. so, i will do that, tomorrow